# What are "hyperthreading" and "virtual cores"?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, multi-processor, hyper-threading

I'm new in this computer terms. So anyone can explain to me what "virtual cores" and "hyperthreading" are at greatest detail a layman can understand?

People told me that virtual cores are imaginary cores acting like a physical core.
If that is so, then can I make my AMD v105 processor single core a dual core processor?

Is it also possible to hyperthread my CPU? Are these functions built in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hyperthreading is a hardware feature and is not portable to other CPUs.  Hyperthreading is essentially a duplication of the architectural and state hardware that surrounds the actual central processing units on a processor core.

It makes a single core processor *look* like a dual-core processor so that the data processing parts of the processor can be used slightly more efficiently.  It is not as good as having another full processor performance-wise, but it does make slightly better use of the processor when under heavy use.

See this picture for a vague example, and if you want to read more then there's a good article on [PCStats](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1302):

[image]